# Is it possible to load Login screen with out launch screen in xamarin ios(visualstudio2013)

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I want to load Login Screen with out Launch Screen. When run the application it showing launch screen some seconds after that it showing our login screen.
Can you please tell me where can i do the modifications.

Comment: Your want you app to start with login screen? This is not really possible, iOS might take some time to start your app. While the system is starting your app the launch screen is shown. It is a static screen, so you could present some kind of empty login screen, then when your app is loaded and show the real login screen the change is minimum.

Comment: Ok @rckoenes Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS it is not possible to not have a launch screen.

The idea of a launch screen is to show something to the user whilst your app is being loaded - Apple generally recommends showing a dummy view of your ui to provide users with the sense that the app is loading quicker than it actually is.

From Apple's guide ([which can be found here](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/)):

> The launch screen isn’t an opportunity for artistic expression. It’s solely intended to enhance the perception of your app as quick to launch and immediately ready for use. Every app must supply a launch screen.

In your case, the best thing you can do is recreate your login screen in the launch screen - generally you do not show text (such as labels) in the launch screen, just the basic structure of your view.